# Google play integrity. Error -2 IntegrityServiceException

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

We are running Google play Integrity to check if the device has all the security requirements we need. However, we seem to be getting this error on Samsung devices running Android 13

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.android.play.core.integrity.IntegrityServiceException
-2: Integrity API error (-2): The Play Store app is either not installed or not the official version. Ask the user to install an official and recent version of Play Store. (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#PLAY_STORE_NOT_FOUND).
```

We are sure that the users do have play store installed. Any way to solve this issue

I've seen that some people recommend setting the Google cloud project number, but we are already doing this

```
 val tokenRequest = IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
            .setNonce(nonceEncoded)
            .setCloudProjectNumber(BuildConfig.GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER)
            .build()
```

Play integrity version -> 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'